# awk script not working

Tags: bash, awk

two files which has component name and version number separated by a space:

```
cat file1
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 94.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.1.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.9
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.6.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 12.23.65

cat file2 
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 94.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.0.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
com.acc.invm:distri_cob 110
```

needed output is: All components from file2 with a higher version than in file1.

We have to ignore components from file2 if that is not in file1, and components with same version and lower version in file1.

In this example the desired output is

```
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
```

tried this awk code but getting data from file2 also

```
cat rst.awk
{ split($2,a,/\./); curr = a[1]*10000 + a[2]*100 + a[3] }
NR==FNR { prev[$1] = curr; next }
(curr > prev[$1]) || !($1 in prev)
/usr/bin/nawk -f rst.awk file1 file2
```

OUTPUT:

```
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
com.acc.invm:distri_cob 110
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
(curr > prev[$1]) || !($1 in prev)
```

should be changed to

```
($1 in prev) && (curr > prev[$1])
```

Since you want to ignore the items in the second file that are not in the first file, your logic is basically

```
if ($1 in prev) {
    if (curr > prev[$1]) {
        print
    }
}
```

but `if (x) if (y)` is equivalent to `if (x && y)`

Comment: currently I am calling 
/usr/bin/nawk -f rst.awk file1 file2
in my script, Is it possible to write content of rst.awk in the script itself?

after that I dont have to check rst.awk file every time weather rst.awk file is present or not.

pls help